# Azure WebApp Linux and KissLog fail to access /tmp path

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, kisslog

I have an Azure webapp ASP.Net API core 3.1 application running on Linux, I use KissLog to log the system, with a certain frequency I get the following errors:

```
C:\Catalin\KissLog-net\KissLog.Sdk\src\KissLog\LoggerFiles\LoggerFiles.cs LogFile :58

Exception:
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '/tmp/KissLog/2d76c974d7d1.tmp' is denied.
 ---> System.IO.IOException: Bad file descriptor
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.IO.FileStream.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.IO.FileSystem.CopyFile(String sourceFullPath, String destFullPath, Boolean overwrite)
   at KissLog.LoggerFiles.LogFile(String sourceFilePath, String fileName)
Inner Exception:
System.IO.IOException: Bad file descriptor
```

this error only occurs on WebApp Linux, I have the same code running on Windows WebApp, and it works well

Comment: Hi!
I am the developer of KissLog. This appears to be a permissions issue, and KissLog SDK can't write files to the temporary folder (when hosted on Linux).
I will investigate this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is triggered when KissLog is trying to log the HTTP response body. If this step fails, the exception is logged and the rest of the execution is not affected.

I have released KissLog 5.0.0, which contains improvements on this functionality.

If possible, please update the sdk to 5.0.0.